# Unable to transform StandardFlowFileRecord error in Nifi with JoltTransformRecord

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

Running nifi with JoltTransformRecord, with custom Transform (jar) to convert json object with nested fields to flat string values.
I'm gussing it's not data specific as it does processed later (cannot share data)
getting the following error in log, cannot see what caused it or what is the effect of this error:

```
    2020-06-23 08:51:53,567 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.n.p.jolt.record.JoltTransformRecord JoltTransformRecord[id=28ac51f8-631b-3186-8c28-f24161614ada] Unable to transform StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=1ba9ae00-bd90-4494-acf4-1748c45d3267,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1592900472023-4, container=default, section=4], offset=50834, length=489],offset=0,name=6dd95a1b-cdbc-49c5-b8ff-0f8c7f7e2d9d,size=489] due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=1ba9ae00-bd90-4494-acf4-1748c45d3267,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1592900472023-4, container=default, section=4], offset=50834, length=489],offset=0,name=6dd95a1b-cdbc-49c5-b8ff-0f8c7f7e2d9d,size=489] already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=1ba9ae00-bd90-4494-acf4-1748c45d3267,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1592900472023-4, container=default, section=4], offset=50834, length=489],offset=0,name=6dd95a1b-cdbc-49c5-b8ff-0f8c7f7e2d9d,size=489] already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=1ba9ae00-bd90-4494-acf4-1748c45d3267,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1592900472023-4, container=default, section=4], offset=50834, length=489],offset=0,name=6dd95a1b-cdbc-49c5-b8ff-0f8c7f7e2d9d,size=489] already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.validateRecordState(StandardProcessSession.java:3229)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.validateRecordState(StandardProcessSession.java:3224)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.transfer(StandardProcessSession.java:1990)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.jolt.record.JoltTransformRecord.onTrigger(JoltTransformRecord.java:371)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My transform:

```
public class FlattenTransform implements Transform {
private final static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

public Object transform(Object input) {
    Object result = input;
    try {
        if (input instanceof Map) {
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) input;
            updateMetadata(map);
            result = flattenMap(map);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

private void updateMetadata(Map<String, Object> map) {
    if(map.containsKey("metadata")){
        if(map.get("metadata") == null) {
            map.put("metadata", new HashMap<String, Object>());
        }
        Map metadata = (Map<String, Object>)map.get("metadata");
        metadata.put("loading_time", Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
    }
}

private static Object flattenMap(Map<String, Object> input) {
    Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (String key : input.keySet()) {
        Object value = input.get(key);
        if (value != null) {
            try {
                if (value instanceof Map || value instanceof List) {
                    Object valueWithoutNull = removeNullFields(value);
                    value = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(valueWithoutNull);
                }
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            output.put(key, value);
        } else {
            output.put(key, null);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

}

Comment: update the post with your flow, processor configs (especially the jolt one), the source data, and expected outcome from the transformation.

Comment: Also, are you using any custom processors or scripted processors? The `IllegalStateException` is unusual.

Comment: Updated with info I can share, thanks.